# Xamarin project with CrossMediaManager can't play local web site can't play

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, plugin.media.crossmedia

I'm using Plugin.CrossMediaManager(Current version) to play VDO or mp3 files.
Try to use URL from local website (IIS) to play them.

I have learned how to use this component and I have set all necessary things.
- Give necessary code to where native platform start.
I have tried with URL form public website: [Link to website](https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4).

It works well, but when I downloaded that file and copy it into my website (IIS) I can't play it.

This works:

```cs
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4");
```

But yhis doesn't work:

```cs
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("http://192.168.220.110:1113/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4");
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my post and sorry for my bad.

Comment: are your sure that local url is reachable from your device/emulator?  If you try to load it in the device webbrowser is it reachable?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that.
I have tested in both of actual device and emulator by opening browser and it is reachable.

Comment: It seems I can use only URL that has https.
I'm trying both of having http URL and not having URL and both of them are public.

Comment: Are you testing on an iOS device? If so, pay attention to the [ATS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats#configuring-ats-options), add the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key to `info.plist` to disable ATS for all domains and internet communication.